# Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 on Sun Virtual Box

Tags: windows

I installed Windows Server 2008 R2 in Oracle Virtual Box,also WAMP server inside Windows server 2008 R2.

I am able to open/access the WAMP server in my Virtual Box guest OS that is the local host.

But I am unable to access the WAMP server from the host OS.

The host OS is Windows 7

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the networking type that you chose for the virtual machine, the default settings is NAT, if you want to access the web server you should give the ip address of the virtual machine on the nat interface.

Try also to disable firewall on the guest os for all the domain and see what happen.

Answer (score 0):

I find that setting the networking to "Bridged" works best. That puts the guest machine directly on the same LAN as the host. It will try to get another IP address on the LAN, and if it works you can address it directly via its IP as you would any other machine.

NAT means that it won't have an address directly on the LAN, so you might not be able to see it.